# Ng-show being ignored while printing?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a table which is hidden from the screen, but it's a div that I'd like to print.
Anyways, I have a ng-show that should hide or show a given category in the table, if it's empty then it shouldn't show while printing.

```
<span ng-show="hasKids" style="font-size:26px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" >Kids</span>
```

If a person has kids, we show this span, if he doesnt we hide this, maybe some CSS would help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need information about the controller that wraps this HTML. Without the context, can't debug hasKids.

Comment: use `ng-if` than the span disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `ng-show` does not remove the element from the DOM, that's why it is still printed.

Instead, use `ng-if="hasKids"` which will remove the element from the DOM if hasKids is false.

Comment: Great, that was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be great if you could accept it as the answer :)